# iptables Port Forwarding — no service with the port

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing, port-forwarding, nat

I have setup a network as in the image below:

[image]

**Firewall (FW)** running CentOS 6 has two physical interfaces with subinterfaces:
eth0:2 — 10.100.1.78/25
eth0:3 — 10.100.1.79/25
eth3 — 192.168.0.21/24
eth3:1 — 192.168.1.21/24

**The task** is to forward packets from **Host C** to either **Host A** or **Host B** on port 990. There is no router in the network and hosts don't see each other.

**My solution:**
Host C needs to connect to Host A.
Host C sends a packet destined to FW (10.100.1.79, eth0:3) on port 990.
FW receives it on eth0:3 and forwards it to Host A (192.168.0.21) with the same port 990

**iptables** is empty and ACCEPT all policy is set, thus no packet is blocked. Here are the NAT rules:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 10.100.1.79 --dport 990 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.21:990
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -d 192.168.0.21 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 990 -j SNAT --to-source 10.100.1.79
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0:3 -d 192.168.0.22 --dport 990 -j ACCEPT
```

**There is no service listening on port 990 on FW**

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
23/tcp    open  telnet
25/tcp    open  smtp
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
631/tcp   open  ipp
10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt
```

Here is the `ip route`:

```
10.100.1.0/25 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.100.1.76
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.21
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.21
```

When I try telnet localhost 990, the following message appears:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

How can I accomplish the initial task? Do I have to have a service:990 running in order to forward packets?

Comment: `There is no router in the network and hosts don't see each other.` I think this is wrong and you are actually using the FW as a router. Please think of reviewing the question.

Comment: Thank you, Alan. The host C doesn't have a default gateway, so it doesn't see the other network. I should clarify the question: Is it possible for iptables to receive a packet specifically sent to FW's ipAddress:990 and port forward it out to Host B's ipAddress:990? (with no service listening on port 990 on FW)

Comment: I may sound strange, and I am starting to think that it's not possible, but just needed a documented support, if such exist :-)

Comment: What happens if you telnet to `10.100.1.79` instead of to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: With that setup forwarding will only work when packets entering through eth0:3. Note that "localhost" uses loopback interface, and you shouldn't mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this from 21 to 22.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 10.100.1.79 --dport 990 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.22:990
```

And dropping the:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -d 192.168.0.21 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 990 -j SNAT --to-source 10.100.1.79
```

I'll explain if it solves the problem.